# Does improper integral converge?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I need to find out if integral converges:

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{(1-x)\ln(1+x)}}$$

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Find out of what order the singularities of the integrand at $0$ and $1$ are.

Comment: What is order of singularities?

Comment: How fast the integrand approaches $\infty$ when $x \to 0$ resp. $x \to 1$.

Comment: So I need to calculate its derivatives?

Comment: No. Just observe, at $x = 0$, the factor $(1-x)$ is approximately $1$, and thus can be ignored. $\sqrt{\ln (1+x)}$ remains. For $x \approx 0$, you have $\ln (1+x) \approx x$, so altogether $\sqrt{\ln (1+x)} \approx \sqrt{x}$, and the integrand goes to $\infty$ approximately like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Comment: That simple. Thank you for explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At zero:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)\ln(1+x)}}\sim_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$
so the given integral is convergent at $0$.

Moreover at $1$ we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x)\ln(1+x)}}\sim_0\frac{1}{(1-x)^{1/2}\sqrt{2}}$$ so the integral exists at $1$ and hence the integral converges.